Confusion over tensor definition of exterior power of a vector space and exterior algebra
I am new to and currently learning about Tensor Algebra and Exterior Algebra. I am confused about the definition of the exterior power of a vector space $V$, $\textstyle \bigwedge^k (V)$, and the exterior algebra, $\textstyle \bigwedge (V)$. I am especially confused about the notion of a $k$-tensor vs a tensor of type $(p,q)$.
I have seen the exterior power defined as follows:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, $T: V^k \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $k$-tensor, $\mathcal{T}_k(V)$ be the vector space of all $k$-tensors on $V$, and $\text{Alt}_k:\mathcal{T}_k(V) \to \mathcal{T}_k(V)$ be the alternation map where $T \mapsto \text{Alt}(T)$. The $k$th exterior power of $V$ is defined as
$$\textstyle \bigwedge^k (V^*) = \mathcal{T}_k(V)/\ker(\text{Alt}_k)$$

The notation $\textstyle \bigwedge^k(V^*)$ confuses me because a lot of other sources use the notation $\textstyle \bigwedge^k (V)$ to denote this same space. However, I feel as though the former notation makes more sense as this space is built from the quotient space of covariant tensors.
Moreover, what's to stop us from using the space of contravariant tensors or mixed tensors to construct the exterior power of $V$? For example, is it possible to define the exterior power of $V$ as the following?

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, $T: (V^*)^k \to \mathbb{R}$ be a tensor of type $(k,0)$, $\mathcal{T}^k_0 (V)$ denote the vector space of all tensors of type $(k,0)$, and $\text{Alt}^k_0:\mathcal{T}^k_0 (V) \to \mathcal{T}^k_0 (V)$ be the alternation map where $T \mapsto \text{Alt}(T)$. Then we can define the $k$th exterior power on $V$ as the following:
$$\textstyle \bigwedge^k (V) = \mathcal{T}^k_0(V)/\ker(\text{Alt}^k_0)$$

If this definition is valid, what would be the analog of this definition for a general tensor of type $(p,q)$?
Lastly, is it valid to define the exterior algebra on $V$ as the following?

Let $\mathcal{T}(V)$ denote the tensor algebra of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and let $\text{Alt}:\mathcal{T}(V) \to \mathcal{T}(V)$ be the alternation map where $T \mapsto \text{Alt}(T)$. Then the exterior algebra on $V$ is given by
$$\textstyle \bigwedge (V) = \mathcal{T}(V)/\ker(\text{Alt})$$

If this is valid, how would one define alternation for a tensor of type $(p,q)$?

Whatever source you're working from is using terrible conventions. The space of multilinear maps $V^k \to \mathbb{R}$ is not the space of $k$-tensors; when $V$ is finite-dimensional that's the space of $k$-tensors on the dual space $V^{\ast}$. The space of $k$-tensors is the tensor product $V^{\otimes k}$; when $V$ is finite-dimensional you can define it as the dual of the space of multilinear functions $V^k \to \mathbb{R}$ but personally I find this unnecessarily indirect and misleading, and in any case it only works in finite dimensions.

@QiaochuYuan Does $k$-tensor without further qualification refer to contravariant $k$-tensors? Because the space of covariant $k$-tensors is defined as the space of multilinear maps $V^k \to \mathbb{R}$, for example in Lee's ISM (at least in finite dimension).

You can form an exterior algebra/exterior power from any vector space. If $V$ is a vector space, so is its dual $V^$; the point being that ${\bigwedge}V$ and ${\bigwedge}V^$ are two different things, the first the exterior algebra of $V$ and the second the exterior algebra of $V^$. The reason you might see a focus on ${\bigwedge}V^$ is because this space is essentially the space of differential forms (with $V$ the tangent space of a point on a manifold).

@Tob: but that's a contravariant functor in $V$! Argh. I suppose conventions differ here, it depends on whether you are thinking of tensors as some kind of generalized functions on $V$ (as with differential forms).
